# Change image size base from the url

Tags: php, .htaccess

how could I change the display image size base from the size given in the url??

www.example.com/photo/90x90/equation.jpg

the size of the equation.jpg should be 90x90 , and if I change the value of 90x90 it will resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str  = "www.example.com/photo/90x90/equation.jpg";
preg_match_all('/(?P<width>\d+)x(?P<height>\d+)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```